# ASP.Net Core 2.0 MVC website Styles and content disappear when opening Bootstrap Modal Dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been beating my head against a rock for hours now.  I am developing a ASP.Net Core 2.0 MVC web app and running it on Ubuntu 16.04 using Nginx.  Everything works beautifully, until I open any type of Modal Dialog while running in production.  While debugging the dialogs work perfectly.  They open and close with no errors or problems.  However when opening them in the production environment the page content disappears and the browser acts as if it is loading the page forever.  There are no errors displaying in Firebug or Chrome when I view the debuggers.  I have googled and googled....

Anyone have any ideas?  Here is the code for the Modals:

```
@model IEnumerable<erp_jbitpro_cloud.Models.Customers.Customer>

@{
    Layout = "_LayoutPart";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            var url = "";
        });
    </script>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create" class="newPopup btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editPopup">Create New</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="CustomerMgmnt" class="btn btn-primary">Back to Customer Management...</a>
</p>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address1)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address2)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ZipCode)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Website)
                </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ZipCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Website)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State.Abbr)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.CustomerId" class="editPopup btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editPopup">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.CustomerId" class="detailsPopup btn btn-default">Details</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>

    <div class="modal fade" id="editPopup" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mylabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="newDialog">
    </div>
    <div class="detailsDialog">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the partial that loads into the Modal:

```
@model erp_jbitpro_cloud.Models.Customers.Customer

@{
    Layout = "_LayoutPart";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="mylabel">Editor</h4>
            </div>
            <form asp-action="Create" class="newDialogForm">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="CustomerName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="CustomerName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="CustomerName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Address1" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Address1" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Address1" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Address2" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Address2" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Address2" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="City" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="StateId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="StateId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StateId"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ZipCode" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="ZipCode" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ZipCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Phone" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Phone" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Website" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Website" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Website" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be going on here?

Comment: check the browser dev tools console to see you are getting any errors. Also i would inspect the network tab to make sure all the needed files are loaded properly / getting a 200 OK response for the calls

Comment: I checked and the bootstrap css and site css files are showing 304 instead of 200...why are they showing 304??

Comment: Ok looks like a caching problem?!!! Going to test out clearing cache and see if the issue resolves.

Comment: Clearing the browser cache doesn’t help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow!  So I solved the issue, thanks to the suggestions made by @shyju !  The problem was that the css files were getting status 304.  I was using the default linking from the template _Layout file for the Production site, once I changed those links everything now works in production.  Just for clarity on what fixed it please see the code below:

Original:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Fixed it:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```